# nginx: How to set expires headers for images in nginx.conf file

Tags: nginx

My images are located **domain.com/assets/img** and **domain.com/images/**

I added this to my nginx.conf file and it disabled my images.

```
location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
expires 1y;
log_not_found off;
}
```

Comment: do you mean it is not serving images to the browser, or it disabled caching or what?

Comment: its prevents the images from displaying in the browser. I also added css and js to...(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ and it disabled the css and js on the page.

Comment: Could you show us your full config? Probably you do not understand how location works.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew, i'v added you configurations to one of my confs and it worked.
Now, on my response headers I have

> Date:**Sun, 03 Feb 2013** 10:47:33 GMT
>   **Expires:Mon, 03 Feb 2014** 10:47:33 GMT
>   
> Last-Modified:Tue, 29 Jan 2013 06:40:59 GMT
>   
> Server:nginx/0.8.53

Looks that your solution its working.

Comment: I've got the same problem as Andrew and it seems it happens when the conf lacks a root directive, maybe yours has it? I'm still looking for a solution...